# Organizing media uploads

Tags: media, uploads

One of my clients wants to transfer his WordPress website to my server. The problem is his website doesn't use sub-folders in his upload folder, and he has more than 1,000,000 files in the root of his upload folder.

Is there a way to organize all his post uploads into folders, without losing the attached links and featured images in the posts?

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume the *problem* isn't as much 1M files, but your server unable to handle it? Logically it worked elsewhere, right?

My opinion is that presenting is as a “problem” to the client might be a little one sided.

It's in realm of technical possibility, but it won't be a smooth process. WP stores image sizes information as serialized PHP data in database. So for each image it would be quite involved operation of adjusting that data. I don't think I've seen anything that automates it away completely for such use case.

My strong concern also would be URLs changing. I imagine site with such quantity of images is likely to receive not insignificant amount of traffic from image searches. Messing that up would be very unfavorable.

Overall client should be probably presented with upsides and downsides of the change, more so if you are going to be charging for it. The best thing for them (and maybe for you) might be to look for system that better accommodates their needs.

Comment: The server can handle the 1m files, the main problem (or difficulties if you will) is the backing up of the media files. The upload folder could only list up to 10.000 files, so what i did, i downloaded 10.000 files then deleted them, then moved to the next 10.000 etc. I'm trying to avoid future issues with backing up the website.